# Any Method for tracking list of my all added friend (Pending Request)

Tags: sql, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

But if i want to check that how many people did i sent friend notification?

I tried The fql query

SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()

But it's showing me received requested friend list.

After that i tried:

SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_from = me()

but it was showing index search error.

When i searched

SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_from = me() AND uid_to = ""

then it returned me result.

Can anyone give me the solution in FQL query or would be good if any graph.api is available for this. Kindly provide me tested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to list all outbound friend requests, you need to store the user IDs in order to check the status of a sent request, or you can list all incoming requests